# Unity - A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade Error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get app bundle. It builds without resolve. But if I resolve before build, I see these error:

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/kotlinx_coroutines_core.version'.

I am using Apple Silicon, Unity 2021.3.29f1

I have seen other issues with this error. There were solutions like "creating new keystore", "restarting Unity", "increasing target API". I have tried all of these but none of them worked.